# Assign products to newly added category in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Hi i am working on extension for categories.i am facing problem regarding categories and products.I have more than 2 categories  with same products.After creating new category I want to assign those products that exist under category1, (category 1 and category 2 have same products).It will remove products from category2 due to my code.My code is :

```
  $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        foreach ($collection as $product) {
                 $categories_pd = $product->getCategoryIds();                              
                    $product->setCategoryIds(array($new_cateid , $category1_id));
                    $product->save();
        }
```

I know that due to setcatgoryIds function its removing other entries.Can anyone know right function or logic to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$categories_pd = $product->getCategoryIds();` you get all existing entries as an array.

Just add new categories here

`$categories_pd[]=$newid1;$categories_pd[]=$newid2...`

Then in `$categories_pd` you have all needed categories so just set it

```
$product->setCategoryIds($categories_pd);
                $product->save();
```

Comment: thanks for your response. i also find another solution like $product->setCategoryIds(array_merge($product->getCategoryIds(),array($new_id,$old_category))).

Comment: Yes good too, I just make it "simple" with more step to let you see and learn how it works :)